# Getting mongo bson error using Docker on Mongoose/Express

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose, bson

I'm working on a small test project and everything was working fine until I added `date-logger` "service" which uses `mongoose`.

I get the following error upon running `docker-compose up --build`:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
Require stack:
- /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js
...
```

Everything else gets started and runs correctly, except for this service which immediately fails as soon as `require('mongoose')` is reached.

Here are some of the important files:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
  redis:
    image: 'redis:latest'
  api:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment: 
      - REDIS_HOST=${REDIS_HOST}
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
      - PG_USER=${PG_USER}
      - PG_HOST=${PG_HOST}
      - PG_DB=${PG_DB}
      - PG_PASSWORD=${PG_PASSWORD}
      - PG_PORT=${PG_PORT}
  date-logger:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./date-logger
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./date-logger:/app
    environment: 
      - EXPRESS_PORT=${EXPRESS_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
  worker:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./worker
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./worker:/app
    environment: 
      - REDIS_HOST=${REDIS_HOST}
      - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '3050:80'
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo
```

`Dockerfile.dev` on `date-logger`

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

`package.json` on `date-logger`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.17.0",
    "mongoose": "~5.5.11",
    "cors": "2.8.4",
    "body-parser": "~1.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "1.19.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon"
  }
}
```

`index.js` on `date-logger`:

```
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// This console.log works
console.log('date-logger hello ---');

// ****!!!! IT FAILS IMMEDIATELY ON THIS REQUIRE !!!****
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let app = express();

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo/date-logger');

const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  value: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);

var port = process.env.EXPRESS_PORT || 8080;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World with Express'));
app.get('/date', (req, res) => res.send('data'));

app.get('/date/all', (req, res) => {
  Item.find({}).exec().then(results => res.send(results))
});

app.post('/date/add', (req, res) => {
  const newItem = new Item({
    value: req.body.value
  });

  newItem.save().then(item => res.send('success'));
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Running RestHub on port ' + port);
});
```

I'm new to devops world so all/any help is super appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to mongoose and not docker,
[check this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2718)

Comment: Yeah, I ran onto that but there are no clear solutions. Weird thing is I use Mongoose/Express on most of my projects and I've never had this issue before until now trying it with Docker.

Comment: Apparently you need to install node-gyp before installing your dependencies, did you try that?

Comment: Yeah, I gave that a shot as well, adding a `RUN` directive with `npm install node-gyp` before `npm install`, as well as adding it to the dependencies. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old but I came across a similar problem recently (but using only docker, not docker-compose).

I solved the problem by removing package-lock.json from my .dockerignore file (it should have never been there at all).

And of course make sure you can run npm install in your local machine, try removing package-lock and node_modulues and running npm install again if you can't. And update any modules you can.